# iOS MDCTextField placeholder text not floating when used in MDCTextInputControllerUnderline

Tags: material-components-ios

The placeholder is not floating above the textfield, any ideas?:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLLPC.jpg

```
@IBOutlet weak var text: MDCTextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var textFieldController = MDCTextInputControllerUnderline(textInput: text)
    text.placeholder = "TEST"
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems as if you aren't retaining your underline controller. Make it a property (var or let outside a method.) That should keep it around so it can do the work instead of leaving the text field to revert to unstyled defaults.

Comment: Thanks Will! That was the problem. Here is the updated code:

 let textFieldController = MDCTextInputControllerUnderline()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textFieldController.textInput = text
    }